# Windows Disk Partition not correctly show partition size changes made from 3rd party partition manager

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

i have a situation where i need to increase the size of my boot partition (C drive) for Windows 10. the system is using 1tb HDD with all of its size being allocated to several partitions as such:

C: 100GB
D: 48GB
E: 300GB
F: 400GB
G: 50GB
H: 60GB

I'm using 3rd third-party application booted from a USB drive to resize the partitions by shrinking the F partition by 100GB and allocating the free partition to the previous partition letter until it reaches the C partition. So the updated partition size of F will reduce by 100GB and C will increase to 200GB total. other partitions does not change.

However, when I boot into the windows, it still shows the old partition size of which the C partition did not increase in size (100GB). I double-checked the disk partition size by booting to the USB drive again and using multiple 3rd party applications, they all show the C drive was already allocated to 200GB.

My assumption is that my attempt to resize the partition did not update the Windows partition table which Windows uses during the boot process. Is there any way to force changes to the partition table to reflect the current value for each partitions (if my assumption is valid and doable) or any other way I can increase the bootable partition (C drive) without damaging the OS?

Comment: Add screenshots.

Comment: Correct language matters in this scenario - `C:` is not the boot partition, it's the OS partition/`%SystemDrive%`. AFAIK, the only way what you describe would occur is if the changes weren't applied in the third-party partitioning program, as the partition table is separate from any OS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows partition should be resized using Disk Management, since not
all third-party partition editors do it correctly.

I suggest running Disk Management, right-click your partition and
select "Extend Volume...".

Note that to increase the size of a partition, it must be followed by
unallocated space that will be incorporated into the partition.

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Extend a basic volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest gparted.
Note: gparted has an APPLY button you must click or changes will be discarded.

Since the C: drive is at the beginning of the drive you need to do more work.
After shrinking F: by 100gb you must them move it forward 100gb.

Then you must move E: forward 100gb
Then D: forward 100gb.

Finally the free space will be next to the C: drive.

Now you can extend the C: drive into the unused space in front of the C: drive.

Answer (score -2):

Use partition magic for Windows 10: https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/partition-magic-windows-10-0528.html

[image: image - Disk Management is a Windows]